# Php Unit not finding class

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm playing with PHPUnit and am getting an undefined method error in my test. I have the following class nested in a folder located in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/stats/includes/models/Stats.php:

```
namespace stats\includes\models;

class Stats
 {  
 public function sluggify($string, $separator = '-', $maxLength = 96)
    {
    $title = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string);
    $title = preg_replace("%[^-/+|\w ]%", '', $title);
    $title = strtolower(trim(substr($title, 0, $maxLength), '-'));
    $title = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $separator, $title);

    return $title;
   }
 }
```

My Unit tests are located in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/stats/Test/createTest.php
The code for my unit test is as follows:

```
namespace stats\Test;

require '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/stats/includes/models/Stats.php';

class StatsTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

 public function testSluggifyReturnsSluggifiedString()
  {
    $originalString = 'This string will be sluggified';
    $expectedResult = 'this-string-will-be-sluggified';

    $url = new Stats();

    $result = $url->sluggify($originalString);

    $this->assertEquals($expectedResult, $result);
 }
```

If I am successfully requiring the class, why is my method undefined?

Comment: "why is my method undefined" --- what does it mean?

Comment: The function "sluggify" is not defined.

Comment: You seem to have omitted the actual error message that you're getting. Also, is `Stats` in a namespace?

Comment: This is my error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method stats\Test\StatsTest::sluggify()

Comment: The Stats class has the following namespace:                  namespace stats\includes\models;

Comment: @krisacorn That error message doesn't match your code at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test class is in namespace `stats\Test` whereas your `Stats` class is in the `stats\includes\models` namespace.

Add this under the `namespace` declaration in `createTest.php`

```
use stats\includes\models\Stats;
```

or simply use

```
$url = new \stats\includes\models\Stats();
```

in your test method.

#### Addendum

It's a reasonably common convention to use the same namespace for your classes and their tests as well as naming your test files after the test suites within (ie, `StatsTest.php` instead of `createTest.php`).

I suggest you have a look at some other big PHP projects on GitHub and pay particular attention to their test suites.